# my dock is not showing

Tags: dock

For some reason my dock doesn't show anything, if I have added favorites, I just let them know how to do it, they might help me.

PS: I don't speak english, I'm using a translator, sorry.
[can you see?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ed2.png)